# Proxy charge through powerbank at charging stations to avoid malware?

Tags: usb

When I travel I see people using USB charging stations, however I don't trust them. Looking up on the subject, cyber security experts and government officials warn not to use them with a cable that can transfer data because of "[Juice Jacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Juice_jacking)". I am not sure why they have them if they are a malware risk and can't understand why they are not made charge-only on the ports themselves.

What I do is charge up a power bank at those charging stations and then use the power bank to charge my device, personally I cannot think of any way this could pose a risk. Is this actually the best way to safely use the USB charging stations at airports etc.?

Comment: "I am not sure why they have them" -- why who has what? You lost your anticidents.

Comment: The risk, if you read about Juice Jacking, is not the legitimate charging stations ... so, the question becomes, "how can I use a potentially malicious charging kiosk safely?" And we have questions about that.